# Задать уровень логгирования в Monolog извне?

Tags: php

Возьмем пример из документации [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog):

```
?php

use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

// create a log channel
$log = new Logger('name');
$log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('path/to/your.log', Logger::WARNING));

// add records to the log
$log->warning('Foo');
$log->error('Bar');
```

**Вопрос:** как задать уровень логгирования (***WARNING*** в `Logger::WARNING`) из переменной (например, `$log_level='WARNING'`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Logger:WARNING` просто константа. Константу можно сохранить в переменную и использовать позже.

```
$log_level = Logger::WARNING
// create a log channel
$log = new Logger('name');
$log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('path/to/your.log', $log_level));
```

Если нужно именно из строки то проще всего использовать словарь.

```
$log_level = 'warning';
$possible_levels = ['debug' => Logger::DEBUG,
                    'info' => Logger::INFO,
                    'warning' => Logger::WARNING, /*other levels */];

$level = $possible_levels[ $log_level ];
$log = new Logger( 'name' );
$log->pushHandler( new StreamHandler( 'path/to/your.log', $level ) );
```

Если нехочется заводить словарь или хочется избежать дублирования уровней, то можно использовать рефлексию

```
$log_level = 'WARNING';
$LoggerRef = new \ReflectionClass( 'Monolog\Logger' );
$level = $LoggerRef->getConstant( $log_level );
$log = new Logger( 'name' );
$log->pushHandler( new StreamHandler( 'path/to/your.log', $level )
```